# What are the best practices when using Laravel Jobs and Events

Tags: laravel, queue

I am developing a back-end API, that must save data to a database before creating a PDF document using the dynamic data being sent. Would it be best practice to put my business logic that updates my models in Laravel Job or would it be better to use a Laravel Job or Event for the creation and compression of the PDF document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queue jobs are used for asynchroniously processing tasks which would normally block the script from executing. For example, sending an email: request/response from SMTP server can take up to 5 seconds under heavy load, thus halting the script for that amount of time, which is not good for end user.

The questions which rise are: what are you gonna do with that PDF? Are you gonna store it on disk, send it to an email, or send it back to the browser, on the same request?

For case 1 and 2, depending on how much information is stored in that PDF, I'd probably dispatch a job for each document for processing. Eventually you can fire an event and set a listener to dispatch the job if you like to — this is better in concept but requires more code to maintain.

For case 3 I'd forget the jobs and events as well. It's a synchronious task and processing it procedurally is a better choice.